# Qt application made in Eclipse doesn't start

Tags: eclipse, qt, ide, mingw

I've been trying for a few hours now to make eclipse, mingw and Qt work, and I can't manage to.

No matter what I try, when I try to run the qt application (using Run or Debug, same thing), no window appears, and after a few seconds, Eclipse says 'program terminated'. Another time I tried (using some different configurations), windows would give that "Program has stopped" error.

If I try to launch the application from outside eclipse, I get a missing .dll error.

I have Qt 4.8.1 installed, latest version of eclipse, and I just installed the latest version of MinGW. I am also using the Qt plugin for Eclipse. I'm running Windows 7.

There are also some other minor problems:

- For some reason I have to rebuild the index after opening/creating a project, or I'll get 'undefined include' errors.
- The build (hammer) icon in the toolbar is grayed/disabled, why could that be?
- For every new project, I need to change the make application to mingw32-make, is it possible to make the toolchain use this make executable or something?

I can't understand why Microsoft Visual Studio just works, I didn't have to set up anything other than install the Qt add-in, and Eclipse is so hard to configure...

Comment: Support for Qt for Eclipse was dropped over a year ago.  Use QtCreator or VS.

Comment: Oh, I see... and there is no way to make this work?

Comment: Probably, but it's going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @cbamber85 I think you should write an answer with the information, maybe others will have the same question.

Comment: I said probably and not yes, because there's _probably_ a way of doing it, but I don't what would need to be done to fix all the issues.  I use Eclipse at work and have nothing against it, but QtCreator is an equally fine IDE and works out of the box (my only complaint is that the SVN support is rubbish, but as you're on Windows you should be using TortoiseSVN anyway).  Instead of battling for days with a plugin that support was dropped for ages ago, you could have been working on your project.